# How to get data that is in the Notes (Quickbooks Notepad) in ItemInventory

Tags: api, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I can't find any way to get to the data stored in the Quickbooks Item 'Notes'.

I am referring to the 'Notes' button on ItemInventory 'Edit Item' Dialog. Once you hit the Notes button, it opens a 'Notepad' and you can enter in text in a large textbox.

Can someone help with the correct API function call to get to this data? I didnt see it in the ItemInventoryQuery Response.

Answer (score 2):

That data is not available and as you said not listed in the OSR.